# Why do some receipts in some shops in Thailand indicate "authorized tourist"?

Tags: thailand, shopping, bangkok, tourism

Why do some receipts in some shops in Thailand indicate "authorized tourist"?

Example from Tops supermarket in Bangkok:

[image]

Comment: To let you know you were at an authorized tourist trap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks like a [The 1 card](https://www.the1.co.th/en/home), but with a generic number and name. Most likely this is because you didn't actually present one of these cards when you made your purchase. Using a generic number like this, you might get some privileges such as discounts on your purchase, but not any points as you aren't in the program. It appears you got a discount of 11 baht on whatever you purchased.